# When to use belongsTo() and when hasOne() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

When defining a one-to-one relationship between models in laravel, we will say :

```
class Model1 extends Model
{
     public function model2()
     { 
         return $this->hasOne('App\Model2');
     }
}
```

and for Model2 we will use `belongsTo('App\Model1')` .

Is there a logic on how to decide on which end we will use each function?

Comment: If you're looping over `Model1::all()` or if you're looping over `Model2::all()` you would each method respectively

Comment: A good example is user > phone.
The phone belongs to the user, that means that if the user does not exist anymore, the phone itself should not exist either.
On the opposite, the user can loose his phone (the phone is deleted) but the user still exists.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, if you have an one-to-one relationship in your database schema, your schema can be improved. Not always, but more often than not.

Comment: @STTLCU can you explain a little more?

Comment: When you have an 1-to-1 relationship, this means that entity A has one and only entity B related to it, and viceversa. What I see from that is that A and B are so inter-related that they can often be combined without any loss of generality (so you have a table C which is composed by the columns of A plus the columns of B). As far as I can remember, I have never used an 1-to-1 relationship in my working experience. During university maybe I used it once, but it felt odd and it was a sign of a bad design. In the end, it has been removed.

Comment: @orestiss anyway, to see if it is advisable to merge these two models into one or not, I'd need much more informations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference between the two is where the foreign key will reside in the database. The belongsTo function should belong to the model whose table contains the foreign key, while the hasOne should belong to a model that is referenced by a foreign key from another table.

Both will work, but you should maintain solid coding practices for other developers that may use your system in the future. Also, this becomes crucial if your foreign key cascades the delete. If you delete model1, should model2 that belongsTo model1 be deleted also?

Comment: the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) states the opposite: the `belongsTo` relation is in the table with the foreign key (`phones`)

Comment: @Moppo actually this is not the case. In the docs the Phone model has the `belongsTo()` method and the `user_id` foreign key as proposed by Mikel.